# Appium - Create Session - Error: Either JSONWP or W3C capabilities should be provided

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I am unable to get Appium to start an Android session and did not find anything related to the error message I am getting when I searched online.

When I run my test Appium dumps this log:

```
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,[{"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"7.0","appiumVersion":"1.11.1","automationName":"UiAutomator2","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"ZX1G22GRHD","applicationName":"Absolute"}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}]]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1552607433945 (16:50:33 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1552607433945 (16:50:33 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Either JSONWP or W3C capabilities should be provided
[debug] [W3C]     at parseCapsForInnerDriver (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/utils.js:58:14)
[debug] [W3C]     at AppiumDriver.createSession (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:262:26)
[debug] [W3C]     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:301:19)
[debug] [W3C]     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:429:26)
[debug] [W3C]     at asyncHandler (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:352:34)
[debug] [W3C]     at app.(anonymous function) (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:489:15)
[debug] [W3C]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [W3C]     at next (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at Route.dispatch (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
[debug] [W3C]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [W3C]     at /Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
[debug] [W3C]     at Function.process_params (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[debug] [W3C]     at next (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[debug] [W3C]     at logger (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/morgan/index.js:144:5)
[debug] [W3C]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [W3C]     at trim_prefix (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at /Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
[debug] [W3C]     at Function.process_params (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[debug] [W3C]     at next (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[debug] [W3C]     at /Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
[debug] [W3C]     at invokeCallback (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
[debug] [W3C]     at done (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
[debug] [W3C]     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/davethomas/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
[debug] [W3C]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
[debug] [W3C]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 5 ms - 738
[HTTP]
```

My test:

```
public class AndroidTestCaseExample {

    public AndroidDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.0");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.11.1");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "ZX1G22GRHD");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"UiAutomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPLICATION_NAME, "Absolute");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    @Test
    public void loadApp() {
        List<MobileElement> elements = (List<MobileElement>)
                driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.EditText");

        for (MobileElement element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element.toJson());
        }
    }
}
```

What does `Either JSONWP or W3C capabilities should be provided` mean?

Comment: The desired capabilities in your log and from your test are vastly different. I don't know why that is, but possibly a clue?

Comment: Just an old log... updated it. Been playing with the capabilities trying to figure it out. @MikeCollins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **ApplicationName> Absolute** to either **App** or (**appPackage** and **appActivity**)

```
//Either add following line in the DesiredCapabilities
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, "Path to your apk file");

//OR add following two capabilities if the app is already installed in the testing device
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "app package name");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity, "app activity name");
```

Comment: `AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE` and `AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY`

Answer (score 1):

**@Dave Thomas**, hi.

Considering [official spec](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/create/) says that

- JSONWP Spec Required capabilities have higher priority than desired capabilities and must be set for the session to be created
- W3C Spec capabilities.alwaysMatch must be set for session to be created; capabilities.firstMatch must match at least one (the first one to match will be used)

I think You should dig into capabilities set-up.
Let me share piece of code that might be helpful for You:

```
        package io.mytestproject.appium.tests;
        import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
        import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
        import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
        import io.testproject.appium.pom.tests.pages.LoginPage;
        import io.testproject.appium.pom.tests.pages.ProfilePage;
        import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
        import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
        import java.net.URL;
        public class PositiveLoginTest {
            private final static String APP_PACKAGE_NAME = "io.mytestproject.demo";
            private final static String APP_ACTIVITY_NAME = ".MainActivity";

   public void setup() throws Exception {
                // Prepare Appium session
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
                capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.ANDROID);
                capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "YOUR_DEVICE_UDID");
                capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, false);
                capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, APP_PACKAGE_NAME);
                capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, APP_ACTIVITY_NAME);
                // Initialize driver
                AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    ......        }
        }
```

Please also see [this article](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/web_and_mobile_test_automation_drivers/) to understand the difference between web and mobile test automation drivers and corresponding capabilities.

And also, providing [the whole listing of Appium Desired Capabilities](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/)

Hope this helps for You,
Regards,
Eugene