# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError once I run my Appium script

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium, appium-android

I’m a new Appium user and I’m following with an Appium tutorial and when I try to run my script I’m gitting the following error :

```
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/AcceptedW3CCapabilityKeys
at io.appium.java_client.remote.NewAppiumSessionPayload.(NewAppiumSessionPayload.java:98)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:175)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:84)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:94)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:95)
at base.main(base.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.AcceptedW3CCapabilityKeys
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
… 15 more
```

I’ve tried to remove the selenium jars and relaunch eclipse and the emulator with no benefits.

here’s my script:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class base {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    File f = new File("src");
    File fs = new File(f,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");
    URL ServerURL = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Demo");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Malek, hi. 
Have You created maven-based project?

Could You pleas ensure that You do have correct and up-to-date dependencies? Obviously You're missing some dependency or maven didnt pull the dependency from the repo.
After You've ensured, please note:

if You have 
selenium and java-client dependencies e.g:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

they might be conflicting each other. Please remove selenium dependency and leave java-client dependency.

After that - 
please call   `mvn clean install` command .   You can learn about maven [lifecycle here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

Second option to try: 
please ensure that You create and initialize capabilities in the correct way.
The difference between JSONWP  and W3C Spec  capabilities You may get here, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55176176/1546574).

And last one advice-  here, in [Comparing and combining web and mobile test automation drivers](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/web_and_mobile_test_automation_drivers/)  article  You may get an example of working code that You may adjust up to Your needs.

Hope this helps for You.
Regards,
Eugene

Comment: Thanks a lot, @eugene.polschikov, I don't know that I need to use maven since in the tutorial that I'm watching he didn't mention that I need to use maven but I'll set it up and retry.

Thanks!

Comment: @Malek, sure . Feel free to upvote the answer. Thanks