# why appium v1.12.1 give this error when i execute test scripts? android version:6.0

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTnw6.png)error information:
[debug] [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'Appium' and platformName 'Android'. Please check your desired capabilities.
it seems there is something wrong about capabilities.but i think it is not wrong in my code.
I can run the scripts without any errors using Appium v1.9.1
why Appium vv1.12.1 will encounter this problem?

```
 Config.initLog(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
   DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, cf.readConf2("uuid"));
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, cf.readConf2("uuid"));
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "6.0");  
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium"); 
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
   AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);




       Detail error info:
[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"6.0","automationName":
"Appium","browserName":"Chrome","udid":"8DF6R16826005016","platformName":"Android","devi
ceName":"8DF6R16826005016"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}}
[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,{"desiredCapabi
lities":{"platformVersion":"6.0","automationName":"Appium","browserName":"Chrome","udid"
:"8DF6R16826005016","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"8DF6R16826005016"},"requiredC
apabilities":{}}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1554197751059 (17:35:51 GMT+0
800 (GMT+08:00))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1554197751060 (17:35:51 GMT+080
0 (GMT+08:00))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Either JSONWP or W3C ca
pabilities should be provided
[debug] [W3C]     at parseCapsForInnerDriver (C:\Users\v.yuanwenfang\AppData\Roaming\npm
\node_modules\appium\lib\utils.js:58:14)
```

Comment: YOU ARE MISSING OS VERSION

Comment: Thanks,but what is os version,can you tell me in detail,bro?

Comment: sorry android version wait let me show you one example

Comment: thanks!waiting for ur detail example~

Comment: have you understand what you have missed or need further help

Comment: sorry,i don't know what i have missed...can you tell me.

Comment: you have forgot platform version like anroid 7.0.1 or 8.1 or 9 likewise

Comment: ohh,android version is 6.0.

Comment: sorry,i'm a fresher in automation testing,Thank you for your guidance。

Comment: have you seen the error it says that you have not given automationName check i have update the answer

Comment: you need to provide capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your desire capabilities should look like this their are also more but this is enough to run normal android automation

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.4");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
```

I have also shared one link with you they have given an example for reference

https://www.toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-test-using-testng/

and you have also forgot to give an `automationName` depends on you what you have to use UiAutomator or UiAutomator2

**Edit**
Either JSONWP or W3C capabilities should be provided ?

this below link will help you

[Appium - Create Session - Error: Either JSONWP or W3C capabilities should be provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173105/appium-create-session-error-either-jsonwp-or-w3c-capabilities-should-be-pro)

Comment: if you satisfy with the answer so please accept it and upvote if you think happy to help

Comment: and please don't use Bro!!! otherwise peoples are so professional here hence they don't care they will directly report you hence please from next time onward keep this in mind . Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: i have modified the code，but there is another error that says:Error: Either JSONWP or W3C capabilities should be provided.

Comment: [debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,{"desiredCapabilities":"platformVersion":"6.0","automationName":"Appium","browserName":"Chrome","udid":"8DF6R16826005016","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"8DF6R16826005016"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}]                                      why there are two null parameters at the beginning of  “with args”，is this the reason?

Comment: which version of client version and appium version you are using.

Comment: ok,i won;t use bro next time.i just thought it's a friendly name that will be acceptd by people 。：）

Comment: appium version is 1.12.1

Comment: you have to update the version and what about java client

Comment: java version is 1.8.0_31

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases             i use v1.12.1, and  the lastes version is 1.12 in the official website ..   o(╥﹏╥)o

Comment: oppps let me check ! Yes sorry my bad wait

Comment: this helped you or not ^.^

Comment: it's solve the problem"Error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'Appium' and platformName 'Android'. Please check your desired capabilities."  but come up with a problem "Encountered internal error running command: Error: Either JSONWP or W3C capabilities should be provided"

Comment: i have updated，the code  and the error info is the newest.

Comment: i have comment have you seen the comment? you need to add the automationName

Comment: Thanks, i can run it successfully with same code after i change the appium version into 1.9.0.